# Wireless charging circuit

Tags: wireless-charging

I'm designing a wireless charging circuit and i've noticed that on the internet there are two types of circuits:
For some schematics the LC circuit is made in series resonace, in some in parallel.
What are the benefits and drawbacks from different types of circuits and in which case should I use each? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you make your images contain more white and have the actual text be even smaller please?

Comment: Judging by your imaging skills, this will be a good challenge for your ability to control impedance to get matched impedance at MPT in some license-free spectrum. So far others have found mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Resonance increases voltage by Q  must be detected by sender impedance regulation.

Series resonance must be transformed also by impedance matching dynamic load to low impedance source with high impedance air coupling by turns ratio.

Both can work depending on your ability to control Q and stray leakage with ferrite no load and Q when coupled at <25% Diameter. Some can go further with design of twin D coils.

11 kW is the current state of the art for automotive WPT at 200kHz.   Mobile chargers tend to use higher RF for smaller Rx coils.

> Create a daily search "google alert" for *WPT mobile* and you can get daily updates in R&D to an email address. Add keywords to focus your feedback.